# problem with parsing characters in a string and inserting a "#" on the location of each difference between the file and the mask

Tags: c#

TextFile1.txt:

```
START FILE 000INDEX 001PRTBNR Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.
```

MaskFile1.txt:

```
START MASK 000INDEX 001PRTBNR Lorum ipsam dolor sit amut, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed da eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna alique.
```

expected output:

```
START #### 000INDEX 001PRTBNR Lor#m ips#m dolor sit am#t, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed d# eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqu#.
```

```
static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string path = @"TextFile1.txt";
            string mask = @"MaskFile1.txt";
            StringBuilder ma = new StringBuilder();
            StringBuilder pa = new StringBuilder();
 
            char MaskStamp = '#';

            Console.WriteLine();

            MaskHandler(MaskFile(mask));
            PathHandler(ReadFile(path));

            object m = ma.Append(MaskFile(mask).ToString());
            object p = pa.Append(MaskFile(path).ToString());

            path = pa.ToString();
            mask = ma.ToString();

            //TestingEquality(path,mask);

            foreach (char c in path) 
            { 
                foreach (char x in mask) 
                { 
                    for(int i = 1; i < path.Length; i++) 
                    {
                        if (path[c] != mask[x]) 
                        {
                            {
                                pa.Insert(i, MaskStamp);
                                Console.WriteLine(i);
                            }
                        } 
                        else {
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
```

My current output is an infinite loop of the value of "i" but before, I had the line where the index is replaced with a different value but was getting the opposite result, meaning it was only placing "#" at the chars that were in both no the differences. Where is the loop not being told to stop, why isn't "else" handling it? Why is it not stopping at the end of the two text files? I basically have destroyed the project trying to figure out how this won't stop, and I am positive that it's not from the methods being used in the Main.

Any solutions that will get me closer to the desired output are appreciated.

EDIT: so far I am not having any luck with the solutions below. The first one seems to be placing the # characters wherever it wants. The second solutions were also not working because the "c" variable is a mystery to me, and it's telling me it's not defined.

I also forgot to mention, that it is supposed to ignore spaces, which was an issue with the first solution.

Comment: I am not sure if I follow the requirement. If the two strings are different lengths as your example shows… then why is the expected output of the “end” of the string … `aliqu#.` … ? … shouldn’t it be `aliqu##` … ? … both strings DO have the period but they are in different positions. I would think if the two string are of a different length, then any result would be questionable.

Comment: Yes, apologies for the confusion

Answer (score 0):

The assignment seems to be this:

> Given two (equal length) strings, compare them character-by-character, and print the character if they are equal, or "#" if they are different in an output string.

This can be massively simplified by using Linq's [`Zip`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.zip?view=net-6.0) method.

```
using System;
using System.Linq;      

var input1 = "abc def 123";
var input2 = "acc dez 125";

var outputLetters = input1.Zip(input2, (one, two) => {
    // for each pair of characters (one and two), check if they are the same
    if (one == two)
        return one; // same, print the input character
    else
        return '#'; // not the same, print #
})
    .ToArray();

var output = new string(outputLetters);
Console.WriteLine(output);
```

This example prints `a#c de# 12#`.

The `one` and `two` variables give you the pairs of characters at each matching index along both strings. For example, the first (0) index of each string would give you `a` for both `one` and `two`, but for the second (1) index `one` would be `b` and `two` would be `c`.

Comment: Further simplifications can be made to this code, such as using a ternary operator with a single-statement lambda, rather than an if statement, and using `string.Join` rather than `.ToArray`-ing the query and using `new string`, as examples.

Comment: So the example text files I provided you are a mere fraction of the actual size of the textfile I am trying to create. The code worked flawlessly, but now i have a PathTooLongException. Any ideas on how to overcome this problem?

Comment: PathTooLong exceptions occur when you the path of the file (file name + directory path its in) is too long. That's a different issue, as nothing on this page has anything to do with writing to files.

Answer (score 0):

A LINQ version:

```
var t = File.ReadAllText("TextFile1.txt");
var m = File.ReadAllText("MaskFile1.txt");

var o = string.Concat(t.Select((c,i) => c == m[i] ? c : '#'));
```

A non LINQ version:

```
var t = File.ReadAllText("TextFile1.txt");
var m = File.ReadAllText("MaskFile1.txt");

var sb = new StringBuilder();
for(int i = 0; i < t.Length; i++)
    sb.Append(t[i] == m[i] ? t[i] : '#');
```

As to what is going wrong for you; this is problematic:

```
foreach (char c in path) 
{ 
    foreach (char x in mask)
    { 
        for(int i = 1; i < path.Length; i++)
```

If you are stepping through two strings looking at character positions you don't need 3 loops to do it. If you think about the logic of this for a moment, for every char in A , for every char in B, for nearly every char in A again, if A and B have 10 chars, this innermost loop will run nearly a thousand times...

If you want to loop and compare the chars in two strings you cannot do it with foreach, especially not nested foreach; every time you nest you multiply the number of operations you carry out by the length of the array. Instead you just run one loop with an integer that goes from 0 to the length of the string. Strings can be accessed as if they were char arrays; `myString[4]` gets the fifth character of a `myString`. You step through each string once comparing the chars in the same positions

Comment: Getting an error from the second solution and the first one isn't doing anything

Comment: The error is on the "c" value

Comment: Still getting an error on the C value not being defined, I would appreciate some help understanding its usage here so I can initialize it appropriatly

Comment: Both seems ok now https://dotnetfiddle.net/0BYGlt

Comment: I fixed a typo on the second one; the c was a holdover from the first, it has been changed to `t[i]`, sorry for the confusion